# Django-cms: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'SITE_ID'

Tags: django, django-cms

I would like to enable my django-cms instance to host multiple sites.
For that I created two different sites in the admin panel.

Unfortunately only one site is shown because I needed to hardcode the SITE_ID in the project settings.

According to https://github.com/django/django/pull/2460 this is not a mandatory setting anymore. But my Django 1.10.7 instance shows the following traceback if I delete it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 24, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 74, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/admin/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cms.admin.pageadmin
  File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/admin/pageadmin.py", line 39, in <module>
    from cms.admin.forms import (
  File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/admin/forms.py", line 85, in <module>
    class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/admin/forms.py", line 86, in PageForm
    language = forms.ChoiceField(label=_("Language"), choices=get_language_tuple(),
  File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/utils/i18n.py", line 76, in get_language_tuple
    return [(lang['code'], lang['name']) for lang in get_languages(site_id)]
  File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/utils/i18n.py", line 23, in get_languages
    site_id = get_site_id(site_id)
  File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/utils/conf.py", line 294, in get_site_id
    return settings.SITE_ID
  File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._wrapped, name)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'SITE_ID'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved to problem differently.
I used the plugin [djangocms-multisite](https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-multisite).

I don't know if it is the best solution but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like SITE_ID is required by Django CMS, it's in the traceback

```
  File "/var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/utils/conf.py", line 294, in get_site_id
    return settings.SITE_ID
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not sure about this. The code (from:  /var/www/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cms/utils/conf.py) looks like, it is only the "last option" if it cannot get it elsehow.

Comment: Hello Tobias, the SITE_ID is required by django CMS.